# My projects are not appearing in eclipse

Tags: java, android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I face strange problem, Yesterday I was checking my projects and also I created a new project to the work-set.

Today when I opened `eclipse` and loaded my work-set I found that my projects are not loaded into `eclipse`. I checked the work-set folder I found that all my files exist in the work-set folder but those projects are not visible nor loaded into eclipse as if they are not exist.

I have also more than one workset,the one that does not appear in `eclipse` named workset00. workset00 folder exist one the hard drive but does not appear in `eclipse`. Unlike others worksets such as workset01 or workset02 they

I hope the I explained my problem clearly.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out your workspace path is set properly to the workspace ur expecting to set or it different.. please check care fully directory by directory. if everything is proper still wont work, then do the following

1. copy all projects some other temporary folder and delete that directory.
2. create new workspace in eclpise.
3. just copy paste all ur project to the new workspace directory.
4. use import project from ecplise.

and your set

Answer (score 0):

Try reimporting them or import them in a new workspace.